# Representatives in Disjoint Set Union

Tags: data-structures, disjoint-union

The goal is to efficiently obtain representatives of every set. Obtaining the root as representative is better since it gives more information about the set; nodes are often augmented with properties of their subtrees.

*For example,* given the sequence of operations

```
make_set(1)
make_set(2)
make_set(3)
union_sets(2,3)
```

[resulting dsu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4rEc.png)

we want to efficiently obtain the parents `<1, 2>`.

A possible solution:

```
s = empty set
for (every node v):
  s.insert(find_parent(v))
```

There are `n` nodes, finding parent has constant amortized runtime, inserting into a set `Theta(log n)`. The worst-case time is `Theta(n log n)`. How could this solution be improved?

If disjoint-set union is ill-suited for this purpose, is there a better approach?

**Edit:** Matt Timmermans pointed out that finding parent takes constant amortized time. And that using the constant time

```
is_root(v):
  return v == parent[v]
```

we can also obtain `Theta(n log n)` worst-case time. Nonetheless, is there an augmentation that would allow for better runtime?

Comment: If `find_parent` uses path compression. then the worst case time is O(n).  Also, `is_root(v)` is very easy to implement.

Comment: No, when `find_parent` uses path compression, it takes amortized constant time. *All of them together* are O(n).